# How to fix the error : "cannot import name 'GPT' from "gpt"

Tags: python, gpt-3

When I run the code below in Google Colab, I get the following error.

Note: I've already installed gpt using pip (!pip install gpt).

**code**

```
from gpt import GPT
from gpt import Example'
```

**Error**

```
cannot import name 'GPT' from 'gpt' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gpt/__init__.py)
```

Could someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Can you provide us a link of documentation/github? And what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I'm watching for Bhat Bavesh's tutorial, which can be found here: https://github.com/bhattbhavesh91/gpt-3-simple-tutorial/blob/master/gpt-pandas-code-generation.ipynb, where he's making a pandas auto code generator using the GPT-3 model.

Comment: You need to clone that github repository and import GPT class directly from gpt.py

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have not imported `gpt.py` from the GitHub repository.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/shreyashankar/gpt3-sandbox/blob/master/api/gpt.py).

- Make sure you keep `gpt.py` in your current working folder
- Do not forget to name your API key to `openai.api_key` as it is the variable in for API key in the gpt.py